# Warning: "Minimum Font Size greater than current font size"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder, uilabel

In my app I use a custom cell that has a set of labels, I see xcode showing warning concerning font size in custom cell xib file:

> warning message file://localhost/Users/mahmoudalgayed/Desktop/Ajurry-date/CustomCell.xib: warning: Unsupported Configuration: Minimum Font Size greater than current font size

Any one knows how to get rid of this warning?

[image]

Answer (score 10):

You have to set the minimum font size so that it's not bigger than the current size. Have you set the minimum size?

Comment: i unchecked Autoshrink option in label's attribute inspector, and it works.thanks!

Comment: Where to set the minimum font size from xCode?

Answer (score 5):

Changing the font size did not work - I still got the error.

So i fixed this by changing the value for Autoshrink from "Minimum Font Size" to "Minimum Font Scale"

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same "Unsupported Configuration" warning when using iOS 7 Text Styles (e.g. Body, Footnote, Subhead...) on a `UILabel`. I fixed it by replacing the `minimumFontSize` attribute with `adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO"`.

Answer (score 2):

The error is specific to the issue at hand. If you have autoshrink enabled, it sometimes defaults the minimum font size to a size larger than what your font may be sized to currently. Perhaps you adjusted a font to a smaller size and as a result the minimum font size is now larger than the actual font.

To correct the behavior, under the section labeled "Autoshrink" adjust the minimum font size to be less than your current font size.

Alternatively, if you do not care about auto-shrinking your text to fit the label size, you can set "Autoshrink" to "Fixed Font Size" and that will also suppress the warning.

Comment: The current font size i have set in my storyboard is greater than the minimum font size. Still i am getting this warning. I need the label to auto shrink. How to fix this?